# How can I obtain a value in a list of dictionaries based on another value of that same dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have the following dictionaries:

```
inicio=[      
{"market":"oranges", "Valor":104.58},
{"market":"apples","Valor":42.55}
]
```

I would like to know if it is possible to get value `42.55` if the value of the key `market` is `apples`.

I was trying something like this:

```
for d in inicio:
    if key['market']='apples':
        print(d['Valor'])
```

Sorry that I do not include further examples,  but I am quite new into dealing with dictionaries and not sure what else to try.

Comment: You need `if d['market']=='apples'`.... why do you expect `key` to be a defined name? Unless you have a `key` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: why do you have such a dictionary? Wouldn't it be better to have a dictionary like `{'apples': {'Valor': 42.55}, 'oranges': {'Valor': 104.58}}`? Then you could just use `inicio['apples']['Valor']` without iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `d` is the dictionary you're looking for:

```
for d in inicio:
    if d['market']=='apples':
        print(d['Valor'])
```

And use equality operator (`==`) instead of assignment (`=`)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
inicio=[      
{"market":"oranges", "Valor":104.58},
{"market":"apples","Valor":42.55}
]

print inicio[1]['Valor']
```

If you have many items with same apples as market then iterate over the list and check if the key equals apples and then the value.
Check this code.

```
for dictionary in inicio:
    if dictionary['market'] == 'apples':
        print(dictionary['Valor'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. Just replace the "=" with "==" in this line:

```
if d['market'] =='apples':
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need the lookup only once then the iterative logic you have provided is alright. One optimization can be applied here -

```
for d in inicio:
    if d['market']=='apples':
        print(d['Valor'])
        break # assuming you only need 1 value
```

However if you need to rerun this logic again, I would suggest you can iterate once and create a mapping of values.

S o eventually the result may become like `{'apples' : 42.55, 'oranges': 104.58}`.
Again assuming there is only one valor for one market.

On the other hand, if there are many valors for each market, you can iterate once and crate a structure like 
`{'apples' : [42.55, 99.99], 'oranges': [104.58, 99.22]}`

Hope it helps.